# Node.js - Azure - Socket.io - Why am I running out of concurrent sockets?

Tags: node.js, azure

Ok, so I have an app that works just fine locally. I deployed it to Azure the other day and I am regularly getting the error:

***IIS Detailed Error - 503.0 - Number of active WebSocket requests has reached the maximum concurrent WebSocket requests allowed.***

I don't understand why...I have read a lot of tutorials, guides, etc about socket.io (and I have been building with it for 4 months locally with no issue).

Here is my connection code.

```
io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
    var handshake = socket.handshake;
    var session = socket.handshake.session;
    clients.push(socket);

    console.log('A socket with sessionID ' + handshake.sessionID + ' connected!');

    // setup an inteval that will keep our session fresh
    var intervalID = setInterval(function () {
        session.reload( function () {
            session.touch().save();
        });
    }, 60 * 1000);

    socket.on('disconnect', function () {
        console.log('A socket with sessionID ' + handshake.sessionID + ' disconnected!');

        var i = clients.indexOf(socket);
        clients.splice(i, 1);

        // clear the socket interval to stop refreshing the session
        clearInterval(intervalID);
    });
}
```

The console logs when people connect and disconnect...this is working just fine.

If I reset my server my code will run for a little while. I know Azure supports 350 concurrent sockets...not sure how a single user fills that up.

I come from a .NET background so I am used to closing connections when I am done with them, but that doesn't seem to be necessary with node.js sockets.

But if I don't need to explicitly close my sockets, then why are my connections piling up?

Thanks for your help,

David

***UPDATE***

So, based on the answer below, I discovered that azure limits the concurrent connections pretty severely on the free plan. I updated to the standard package to get the full 350 connections.

Of note, I learned that if you use this command:
    io.sockets.manager.server.connections

you will get a count of the current connections. This plainly showed me that even by myself I was using 7 (which is why the free plan died). Now I just need to figure out why...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The blog [post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazure/archive/2013/11/14/introduction-to-websockets-on-windows-azure-web-sites.aspx) states:

•Free:  (5) concurrent connections per website instance
•Shared: (35) concurrent connections per website instance
•Standard: (350) concurrent connections per website instance

The 350 concurrent connections limits applies only to "Standard" Windows Azure Web Sites. Are you in fact using Standard?

Comment: No, I am on the free plan currently, but I am still surprised that I am using 5 connections at once...by myself...

Comment: I upgraded myself to a "standard" site...but I am still curious why I ran out of the 5....

Comment: Thank you for the blog post Niel...and this does raise the question...does this mean that I need to have an instance for every 350 users on my site at one time? So...for 10,000 concurrent users I would need about 30 servers?

Comment: The link is dead